# How to call "where" clause conditionally? prisma

Tags: prisma

how to filter record conditionally in prisma? For example, I have variable `sortByYear` that could contain either `undefined` or `integer`.

I just want to ask if there are any ways to refactor the implementation below. I have tried looking to their [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#relation-filters) but I can't find one.

```
let result = [];

if (sortByYear) {
    result = await prisma.project.findMany({
        where: { provider_id: 50 }
    })
} else {
    result = await prisma.project.findMany()    
}
```

In laravel we can refactor this by using `when` clause that checks a variable first before executing the query. [laravel when-clause](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a combination of spread syntax operation and ternary operation to accomplish this:

```
const result = await prisma.project.findMany({
  where: {
    ...(sortByYear ? { provider_id: 50 } : {}),
  },
});
```

Spread Syntax:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Conditional Ternary:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: nvm. i figured it out for multiple operator. thanks!

Comment: If you user the `OR` operator, one of your conditions must be truthy to return any results: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#or