# What is a better way of constructing a filters object from query params?

Tags: nestjs, prisma, query-string

I want to know what is a better or a "best practise" way of constructing filters object from query params which are optional so the code doesn't go messy (Nestjs, Prisma with Postgres).

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
getHomes(
    @Query('city') city?: string,
    @Query('minPrice') minPrice?: string,
    @Query('maxPrice') maxPrice?: string,
    @Query('numberOfBedrooms') numberOfBedrooms?: string,
    @Query('numberOfBathrooms') numberOfBathrooms?: string,
    @Query('minLandSize') minLandSize?: string,
    @Query('maxLandSize') maxLandSize?: string,
    @Query('propertyType') propertyType?: PropertyType,
  ): Promise<HomeResponseDto[]> {
    const price =
      minPrice || maxPrice
        ? {
            ...(minPrice && { gte: parseFloat(minPrice) }),
            ...(maxPrice && { lte: parseFloat(maxPrice) }),
          }
        : undefined;

    const landSize =
      minLandSize || maxLandSize
        ? {
            ...(minLandSize && { gte: parseInt(minLandSize) }),
            ...(maxLandSize && { lte: parseInt(maxLandSize) }),
          }
        : undefined;

    const filters = {
      ...(city && { city }),
      ...(numberOfBedrooms && { numberOfBedrooms: parseInt(numberOfBedrooms) }),
      ...(numberOfBathrooms && {
        numberOfBathrooms: parseInt(numberOfBathrooms),
      }),
      ...(price && { price }),
      ...(landSize && { landSize }),
      ...(propertyType && { propertyType }),
    };
```

I'm building a filters object which I'm providing to the `where` object of Prisma service, so it follows its rules like "greater then or equal" as `gte` key and so on.

I thought about creating custom pipes for each of the param, or creating a generic one where we can pass an argument for a object key. For example, if we don't pass any argument to the pipe - value will be transformed to the object with the same name in the object key. But if we pass a `gte` or `lte` as an argument to the pipe - value will be transformed to the object, but name of the key will be `gte` or `lte`.

Also, I've heard about query builders, but it means that I have to write bare SQL queries?

I'd be grateful if you provide an example, thanks!

Comment: Does your existing filter object work as expected if you pass it in the where clause of Prisma query? Do you need an example of implementing this query with query builder?

Comment: Yes, it does work as expected, but I think that the way that I created filters object is kinda bad?..
If it's better to use query builder instead - I would be grateful for an example!

Comment: The approach you mentioned is the correct way. Here is another answer which recommends the same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72197774/how-to-call-where-clause-conditionally-prisma